# How to Determine Cosine, and Sine Given $\tan^{-1}x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem was, "for $0 < x < 1$, express and simplify in therms of $x$:  $\sin[2\tan^{-1}(x)]$".

My professor figured out that, $\sin[2\tan^{-1}(x)] = \frac{2x}{x^2+1}$, using the Double Angle Sine identity.

The Double Sine identity is, $\sin2\theta = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta$.

How did he know what values to use for Cosine and Sine in this equation?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\sin^2(y)+\cos^2(y) = 1 \implies \tan^{2}(y)+1=\frac{1}{\cos^2(y)}.$$
Consequently, if 
$$\tan^{-1}(x) = y \implies x=\tan(y) \implies \cos(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}, \sin(y)=?$$

Comment: There is a missing step: as is, $\cos y$ is only known to be $\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$. However, $\mathrm{arctan}\,x\in]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$, so the cosine is nonnegative.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I left it purposefully to let the OP figure out the details.

Comment: That's a good point :) +1

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut If you want to use the “perverse notation” (as D. E. Knuth calls it), use `\arctan x\in\mathopen]-\pi/2,\pi/2\mathclose[`, that renders $\arctan x\in\mathopen]-\pi/2,\pi/2\mathclose[$.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, good to know. Why perverse? That's the notation I learned and used since high school and through all my university curriculum. I find it clear, and more readable than alternative notations, especially in handwriting.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I agree with Knuth on this: I find it confusing and unreadable. `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

Consider a right triangle whose other two angles are $\theta =\tan^{-1}x$ and $\frac{\pi}2-\theta$.

If the legs have lengths $1$ and $x$ (say the side opposite $\theta$ has length $x$) then the hypotenuse has length $\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

It follows that $\sin\theta=\frac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and $\cos\theta =\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.